# Asymptotics of Moments for Spherically-Truncated Gaussian Random Variable

Tags: probability-theory, statistics, asymptotics, taylor-expansion, normal-distribution

Suppose I fix a quadratic function $q:\mathbb{R}^d \to \mathbb{R}$ given as

\begin{align}
q(x_1,\cdots, x_d) = \frac{1}{2} \sum_{i=1}^d a_i x_i^2 + \sum_{i=1}^d b_i x_i.
\end{align}

I allow $a_i, b_i$ to be **both positive and negative** (so the `Gaussian' in the title should be interpreted somewhat loosely).

I now define a family of probability measures $\{\mu_r\}_{r > 0}$ by the density

$$\mu_r(x) = \frac{1}{Z(\mathbf{a,b}, r)} \exp(-q(\mathbf{x})) \cdot \mathbf{I}[\| x\|_2 \leqslant r]$$

where $Z$ is the appropriate normalising constant.

More simply, I look at the $L^2$ ball around the origin with radius $r$ and charge it with density $\propto \exp(-q)$.

Let $X_r \sim \mu_r$. I'm fairly sure that as $r \to 0$,

\begin{align}
\mu_r &\triangleq \mathbf{E}[X_r] &= \mathcal{O}(r) \\
\Sigma_r &\triangleq \mathbf{Cov}[X_r] &= \mathcal{O}(r^2)
\end{align}

and moreover, that one can Taylor expand these expressions around $r = 0^+$, i.e.

\begin{align}
\mu_r &= \sum_{k \geq 1} m^{(k)}(a,b) r^k \\
\Sigma_r &= \sum_{k \geq 2} S^{(k)}(a,b) r^k
\end{align}

What I would like is to get $m^{(1)}(a,b)$ and $S^{(2)}(a,b)$ in relatively explicit form. Higher-order terms would also be of interest, but the leading terms are my main goal.

Answer (score 2):

Change variables, writing $x = rz$, and expressing your moments as ratios of integrals over the set  $S=\{z:\|z\|_2\le 1\} $. After your change of variables, $q(x)$ becomes $r^2 q_2(z) + rq_1(z)$, where the  $q_i$ are the pure quadratic and and pure linear parts of $q$.  You will also pick up powers of $r$ coming from the Jacobian.  Now your integrand has a Taylor expansion in $r$, and the desired asymptotics can be read off by standard techniques.  Since the range of integration $S$ is compact, you can  derive error estimates and concoct a dominated convergence theorem justification for the calculation.

In summary: change variables, expand the integrand in powers of $r$, discard all but the first few terms, integrate the remaining few terms.

Comment: Thanks - yes, this makes sense. It involves doing some integrals over $S$ which take a bit of work, but I can't think of any simpler way of doing things at present.